# How to add boolean attributes / data-attributes in Play 2.0 templates?

Tags: playframework-2.0

does anybody know how to add `boolean attributes` like `autofocus` to scala templates?

Example: `autofocus`:

```
<input autofocus />
```

For now I use:

```
'autofocus -> "autofocus"
```

This prints:

```
<input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" />
```

And how to add custom data-attributes? Thanks!

Comment: And what is wrong with your method?

Comment: It works, no problem. But you should be able to add those attributes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `None`, like this:

```
@inputText(
  loginForm("username"),
  '_label -> Messages("usernameLabel"),
  'required -> None,
  'autofocus -> None
)
```

It will output an element like this:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" required autofocus>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but still I (hope) think there should be an easier way in scala!

```
'autofocus -> "autofocus"
```